Creation in a Biblical sense of producing material out of nothing
Is there a word, phrase or idiom that means creation, in a Biblical sense of producing material, out of nothing?
Example; In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
Is there no concise term for creating something out of nothing pertaining to the universe?
Could the term genesis be used in this context? Merriam-Webster defines it

: the origin or coming into being of something


Does the term ex nihilo count?

Why? Because it doesn't happen very often, and the sentence "God created the heavens and the earth" is understood from the wider theological context.

Fred Hoyle used the term "continuous creation" in his steady-state cosmological model. To allow for the universe to have been expanding forever, he posited that hydrogen atoms would just appear in a vacuum.

Genesis doesn't necessarily mean creation from nothing, and it's often used today for human creations, e.g. artworks or inventions. Even God didn't create everything from nothing, particularly the version in Genesis 2. You should use "creation from nothing" or "creation ex nihilo" if you want to be clear.

The space-time-matter universe is of a different ... order? from 'eternity'. It's quite possible that where the two connect, Earthly languages haven't the ability to fully describe the heavenly. I take 'nihilo' to mean 'not space-time-matter', which is pretty vague.

@Mari-LouA Done! Normally I'm the one complaining about people posting answers as comments.

Please provide an example sentence that shows the context. Are you pulling a rabbit out of a hat or explaining the existing of a particle?

Words and phrasing related to Religion can be quiet specific, and not used outside of a religious sense.  Good work for clearly stating that.

I will remove the close vote when you give an example sentence. In your question you have a noun. Is a noun what are you looking for? And when you say "in a biblical sense" do you mean that you're looking for a word for the creation of the Universe? You say "material" so it's not clear.

"by magic".......

Why is there no apparent, clear and concise literary definition entry   of the term “CREATE” used in the sense of materializing something out of nothing which is the present day theological sole basis of the entire existence of the physical planet and its inhabitants there in, along with the rest of the whole of the supposedly know universe? I am fascinated at the fact that this question was posted to this site and it remains inconclusive for 11 year's with over 91,000 views. Why was this simple question abounded? This question is NOT a closed matter until it is sufficiently answered.

Doesn't creation already mean making something out of nothing? "cre·ation:
the action or process of bringing something into existence"

@RoaringFish If we're being strict, yes. I was once speaking with an alumnus of my old college (SJC--not a religious school by a long shot--) who told me that during his final paper's oral defense the panel stated emphatically, "only God can create."

The term ex nihilo might work. TFD defines it as "out of or from nothing." It's often used in theological contexts like the one you've described, as Wikipedia explains.

The common expression, at least in American English, is to say something was built from scratch.
Another, slightly less informal one is built out of nothing.

This is used when something is built from obvious starting materials.

The word "manifestation" comes pretty close to what you're looking for.

Some of your answers here are not bad, but on this site supporting references are encouraged.

I can see the connection; Vocabulary.com says  '... if something spiritual becomes real, it is said to be a manifestation.' The snag is that many believe that the spiritual realm is the true reality, and our space-time-matter universe rather less substantial (despite appearances).

@fev If I'm dinged for not including a definition that could very easily be obtained by the reader with just a couple of commands on the same device on which they're already reading my contribution, then a certain quote by a certain prophet concerning the distribution of pearls before a porcine group comes to mind.
